# how to exit a task without errors [Jenkins]?

Tags: jenkins

**Problem:**

Depending on my script in my Jenkins task, I sometime wants to quit the `task` marked as successful in the middle of a code section. Is that possible?

I tried using exit code in script, but that doesn't exit `Jenkins`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible you could use `exit 0` - success `exit 1` - failed(or any other number)

Comment: I do so, which goes to the next step in Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Id depends on how much call levels you currently on. Try executing several exit commands like:

exit 0
   exit 0
   ...so on

Alternatively see [Is there a way to write a bash function which aborts the whole execution, no matter how it is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893667/is-there-a-way-to-write-a-bash-function-which-aborts-the-whole-execution-no-mat) . There should be a way to kill process with a successiful return code.

One more reference: https://serverfault.com/questions/390846/kill-a-process-and-force-it-to-return-0-in-linux

Comment: thanks!! However I'm in a Jenkins environment, it did not work. I'm actually able to exit the batch, but then Jenkins execute other steps which I want to skip.

Comment: You want to use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin then. Just split your job to logical parts and then define some variable, which based on results will be used to indicate whether or not do you want to perform the next steps.