# Test a "exit process command" in bash script by using shUnit2

Tags: bash, shell, unit-testing, shunit2

According to a trick from this question [is-there-a-way-to-write-a-bash-function-which-aborts-the-whole-execution...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893667/is-there-a-way-to-write-a-bash-function-which-aborts-the-whole-execution-no-mat)

My example code (example.sh):

```
trap "exit 0" TERM
top_pid=$$

evalInput(){

    cmd=$1

    if [[ $cmd =~ ^\ *exit\ *$ ]]; then
        kill -s TERM $top_pid
    elif [another command]
        ...
    fi
}
```

If I type `evalInput "exit"` then this process will be killed with exit status zero.

Test file:

```
testExitCmd(){
    . ./example.sh
    ...
    evalInput "exit"
    ps [PID of `evalInput` function]
    # `ps` command is failed if evalInput is killed. 
    assertNotEquals "0" "$?"
}

. shunit2
```

My idea to test `evalInput` function is very simple, just use `ps` command to make sure that `evalInput` function is killed but the problem is how I can done this? The important issue here is **when you try to execute `evalInput` that mean you also kill `testExitCmd` function**.

I've tried many ways already e.g. using `&` to put `evalInput` to another process and bla bla bla. but I still get an error like `shunit2:WARN trapped and now handling the (TERM) signal`. As I understand, this indecate that I try to kill my test function process.

Please carefully test it, I don't think just only your imagination can solve this problem but please test a code. If you are on `OSX` you can simply install `shUnit2` via `brew` and simply run it by `./your_test_script.sh`

Answer (score 1):

```
trap "exit 0" TERM
top_pid=$$

evalInput(){

    cmd=$1
    echo "CMD: $cmd"

    if [[ $cmd =~ ^\ *exit\ *$ ]]; then
        kill -s TERM $top_pid
    fi
}

testExitCmd(){
    evalInput "exit" &
    echo "Test evalInput"
    ps [PID of `evalInput` function]
    # `ps` command is failed if evalInput is killed. 
    assertNotEquals "0" "$?"
}

testExitCmd
```

Output

```
 Test evalInput
 CMD: exit
```

Does that help at all?

Answer (score 1):

Let's me ans my own question, I found some tricky way, the procedure is

1. Spawn target program as child process and put it to a background,
2. Run child process then stop it for 1 second,
3. In parent process, save PID of child process to file `tmp`,
4. Child process is awake then read PID from `tmp` to `$top_pid`,
5. The child process now knows its PID, then running a kill command should be work.

My example code (example.sh):

```
trap "exit 0" TERM
top_pid=$$

evalInput(){

    cmd=$1

    if [[ $cmd =~ ^\ *exit\ *$ ]]; then
        kill -s TERM $top_pid
    elif [another command]
        ...
    fi
}
```

If I type evalInput "exit" then this process will be killed with exit status zero.

Test file:

```
testExitCmd(){
    (
        . ./example.sh
        sleep 1 # 1) wait for parent process save PID to file `temp`
        top_pid=`cat tmp` # 4) save PID to `top_pid`
        evalInput "exit" # 5) kill itself
    )&
    echo "$!" > tmp # 2) save PID of background process to file `tmp`
    sleep 2 # 3) wait for child process kill itself
    child_pid=$!
    ps $child_pid # `ps` command is failed if evalInput is killed. 
    assertNotEquals "0" "$?"
}

. shunit2
```