# Stopping script from nested function

Tags: bash

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function_1() {
    function_2
    printf world
}

function_2() {
    printf "hello "
    return 1
    printf "not printed"
}

function_1
```

which prints `hello world`. I would like to stop the execution of the script in function_2 after the first `printf`. So the script should only print `hello`. I tried `return 1` but this only returns back to function_1. I also tried to send a kill signal as proposed in [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893667/is-there-a-way-to-write-a-bash-function-which-aborts-the-whole-execution-no-mat) but I got the same result as with `return 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add an `exit 0` to exit the script with a 0 exit status at the desired point :

```
function_2() {
    printf "hello "
    exit 0
    ...
```

Comment: Thank that works. But if I put these two functions in `.bashrc` then call `function_1` from the terminal, the terminal gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the `exit` built-in. From the [Bash manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#SHELL_BUILTIN_COMMANDS):

> **`exit`** [*n*]
>
> Cause the shell to exit with a status of *n*.  If *n* is omitted, the exit status is that of the last command executed.  A trap on `EXIT` is executed before the shell terminates.